# php passing by reference not working

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm just trying to understand passing by reference in PHP by trying some examples found on php.net. I have one example right here found on the php website but it does not work:

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    return $var++;
}

$a=5;
echo foo($a); // Am I not supposed to get 6 here? but I still get 5
```

This is an example found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Can anybody tell me why am I getting 5 instead of 6 for the variable $a?

Comment: It increases the $var after the echo statement is executed i guess. Try doing `echo ++$var;`

Comment: @pinusnegra: To figure out how it works?  Seems simple enough to learn from...

Comment: @pinusnegra Read first line: "I'm just trying to understand passing by reference in PHP by trying some examples found on php.net."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code and the example code is not the same. Is it a wonder they behave differently?

To see the behavior you expect, you have to change `$var++` to `++$var`.

What happens here is that while the value of `$a` **is** 6 after the function returns, the value that is returned is 5 because of how the post-increment operator (`$var++`) works. You can test this with:

```
$a=5; 
echo foo($a); // returns 5
echo $a; // but prints 6!
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$a++` returns `$a` then increments by one.

To do what you are trying to do you will need to do `++$a`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with the [increment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), rather than passing by reference. If you check the manual, you'll see to exhibit the behaviour you desire, you must change `foo()` to use pre-increment instead of post-increment, like so:

```
function foo(&$var)
{
    return ++$var;
}
```

Now:

```
> $a = 5;
> echo foo($a);
6
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this works just fine. `$var++` returns the value of `$var`, then increments the variable. So the returned value is `5`, which is what you `echo`. The variable `$a` is now updated to `6` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the actual variable:

```
echo $a; // 6
```

If you increment before you return, your example will work though:

```
return ++$var;
```

Answer (score 0):

not directly related to the question, only the subject.
There does seem to be a PHP bug ...

```
$arr = array();
$arr["one"] = 1;
$arr["two"] = 2;
$arr["three"] = 3;

foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) {
$v += 3;
}

foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
echo("\n".$k." => ".$v);
}
```

outputs:

```
one => 4
two => 5
three => 5

(changing '$v' to '$val' (or some other variable name other than '$v')       
in the second (i.e. last) 'foreach' will result in the expected correct
output (one => 4 two => 5 three => 6)
```